# Android database - curser and adapter

Tags: android

Quite new to Android development, can manage the more simple tasks but never dealt with databases before. I have managed to get so far, however, when trying to output all results from the databases, which has been created, i am only receiving references to the record not the actual values. Debugging shows that the values are being assigned correctly, however, are showing the object reference and not the values them selves. What i see is a list similar to:

com.example.testdb.myapplication.Films@42ff37f0

Please see below for my code:

```
// Getting All Films
    public List<Films> getAllFilms() {
        List<Films> filmList = new ArrayList<Films>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM film_table";

        SQLiteDatabase db = new MyDBHandler(this).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        ArrayAdapter<Films> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Films>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,filmList);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Films film = new Films();
                film.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                film.setfilmName(cursor.getString(1));
                film.setFilmActors(cursor.getString(2));
                film.setFilmDirectors(cursor.getString(3));
                film.setfilmDescription(cursor.getString(4));
                film.setfilmFave(cursor.getString(5));
                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                filmList.add(film);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return Film list
        return filmList;
    }
```

I would very much appreciate any input which may guide me in the right direction. I have tried many methods to no avail.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i didn't post sooner. In the end i fixed the issue using the following code, which outputs into the list similar to you answer, however, without the floater element...

```
String[] columnName = new String[]
            {MyDBHandler.COLUMN_NAME, MyDBHandler.COLUMN_ACTORS, MyDBHandler.COLUMN_DIRECTORS,MyDBHandler.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, MyDBHandler.COLUMN_FAVE};
    int[] displayName = new int[]
            {R.id.filmNameEdit, R.id.filmActors, R.id.filmDirectors, R.id.filmDescription, R.id.filmFave};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_listview,cursor, columnName, displayName);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks for all the suggestions. This turned out to be the most simple answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have to guess a little bit here because you don't have more code posted.

You say you have a list that is showing the output of the default `toString()` method for your Films object.

I am guessing your list adapter is using the default `getView()` method, since the default behavior is to print the `toString()` output for the item.

If you want to see the database values of your Films object formatted into a list, you have to extend a list adapter class like BaseAdapter or create a class that implements `ListAdapter`, then override the `getView()` method to create a View that contains your values.

Have a look at `ListAdapter.getView()` and see if that will solve your issue.  If not, you'll have to post more code and be more specific about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the adapter before you are retrieving the values from database, hence there would be no data in the adapter. Moved setting the adapter after retrieving values from DB and after setting them in `Films` object.

```
public List<Films> getAllFilms() {
        List<Films> filmList = new ArrayList<Films>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM film_table";

        SQLiteDatabase db = new MyDBHandler(this).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Films film = new Films();
                film.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                film.setfilmName(cursor.getString(1));
                film.setFilmActors(cursor.getString(2));
                film.setFilmDirectors(cursor.getString(3));
                film.setfilmDescription(cursor.getString(4));
                film.setfilmFave(cursor.getString(5));
                filmList.add(film);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
ArrayAdapter<Films> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Films>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,filmList);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
return filmList;
```

}

Also add a custom adapter to display the value from the class Film:

```
public class MyClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Films> {

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView filmname;
        private TextView actors;
        ................
    }

    public MyClassAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Films> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.film_layout, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.itemView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemView);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Films item = getItem(position);
        if (item!= null) {
            // My layout has only one TextView
            // do whatever you want with your string and long
            viewHolder.itemView.setText(String.format("%s", item.getfilname));
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Layout for the listrow(film_layout.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
         .................... //Form how each row should be displayed    

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Tutorial how to create a custom listview [here](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I am still receiving the same issue, no values for the database are being output. Thanks

Comment: k..i assume you dont have a custom adapter to display the Film class data. I just updated the answer. This should fix your issue.